# Manjaro’s “triple boot” GRUB bootloader shows Windows 11 with strangers lines

Tags: grub, manjaro, lubuntu

I’ve installed Windows 11, Lububtu and Manjaro.
When I started with Lubuntu’s GRUB with Windows, it started normally.
However, when I installed Manjaro it now shows like “strange lines”, and spots, but Windows 11 boots normally.
I also unchecked “Fast Boot” option, and Lubuntu’s GRUB shows Windows 11 as “Windows Vista”.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know why this happens or if it is a bad thing or how to achieve a more cleanly looking boot process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using “Boot repair” software.
It puts Lubuntu’s Grub instead of Manjaro and now boots okay.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment.

I've documented some steps I used to resolve another issue, in case it was of use for anyone who had a specific issue on the following answer. Have a look at 'Get Grub to detect other OSs on other partitions' and see if that resolves your issue:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1442750/689452

(Although ordinarily, I would answer a question thoroughly for the sake of keeping the question/answer together, and keeping all notes on it in one place, I'm not going to copy it all to Unix SE site, as it is on AskUbuntu which is part of SE)

---

Alternatively, it might be worth having a look at Grub GUI, e.g. https://itsfoss.com/customize-grub-linux/

It gives instructions to install Grub-Customizer:

For Manjaro, this is `sudo pacman -Sy grub-customizer`

For Debian based, this is: `sudo apt install grub-customizer`

The article (as do many others) explains how to use it, but basically, you can rename the